# problems in SQL data could be due to a bad executable

Tags: c#, sql

Using c# software for 3 yrs.  Now, since 14th of august there is a problem with a table named `summary` having a column named `jcdate` which keeps updating itself to the 14th of august on its own.

Even if I pass a query to change the date it gets back to 14/08/2013 in a few moments.

Can it be due to a corrupt executable?

Comment: What SQL product is this?  And have you checked for Column Defaults and Table Triggers?

Comment: Please show what data manipulates the data - ideally the SQL or Linq.

Comment: Are you sure the update is coming from your application?

Comment: Perhaps your software has an expiration date? :-)

Comment: Is the database in question a SQL Server?

Comment: Perhaps you need to investigate if the table has a trigger on it use the profile tools that are available to you

Comment: Very unlikely to be a software corruption issue - software issues are more likely to cause unexpected crashes or software that doesn't start up rather than normal operation with the odd strange data manipulation quirk. Profile the database after you change the value and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

While it's impossible for the S/O community to know what is communicating with your database if even you don't, there is something you can do to possibly help.  You will need to profile your database using a sql profiler tool if there is one available for your database.  SQL Server, for example, uses a tool aptly named SQL Profiler.  With a profiler tool, you can monitor all I/O that is occurring on your database. A little detective work will be involved, but I believe this is the direction you need to be going.

Comment: Thanks a million in addition to that the date replacement happened to stop its activity on its own since today morning, but still i shall try the sql profiler to keep in view for the future. Thanks once again

Comment: What i happened to realize was that there was a query in the executable that dint have a where clause accidentally, and for some reason it was never triggered, something activity on the 14th fired it and it started replacing dates, and as of now all is fine thanx to u all keep up the good work

Comment: Good work.  I'm sure we've all left out a where clause from time to time.